# Angular Side Pannel Information Won't Show

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where when you click a button of an item, a side pannel opens, and you can see some data in it. I'm currently getting the error below when I click the preview button. Furthermore, I could not figure out the problem. What can be the problem?

[image]

Main Screen HTML:

```
<button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Preview" class="sidebar-toggle"
                                    (click)="openSidebar('sticker-preview-sidebar', row.StickerData)">
                                    <mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon>
                                </button>
<fuse-sidebar class="sidebar centra details-sidebar fuse-white" name="sticker-preview-sidebar" position="right">
        <sticker-preview [StickerData]="previewStickerData"></sticker-preview>
    </fuse-sidebar>
```

Main Screen TS:

```
previewStickerData: IStickerData;
 openSidebar(name: string, stickerData: IStickerData): void {
      this.previewStickerData = stickerData;
      this._fuseSidebarService.getSidebar(name).open();
  }
```

Side Bar HTML:

```
 <div class="content fuse-white ml-24 mr-8 h-100-p" fusePerfectScrollbar>
        <div class="label-list">
            <p>
                Sticker Info
                <span>{{stickerData.StickerData}}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Side Bar TS:

```
private _stickerData: IStickerData;

  @Input()
  set StickerData(prm: IStickerData) {
      if (this._stickerData != prm) {
          this._stickerData = prm;
      }
  }
  get StickerData(): IStickerData {
      return this._stickerData;
  }

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IStickerData>;



  constructor(
    private _router: Router, 
    private _fuseSidebarService: FuseSidebarService, 
    private _productionService: ProductionService) {
      
}
```

Comment: `row.StickerData`, where does the `row` comes from?

Comment: Comes from the interface IStickerData

Comment: The template does not have the reference to that variable, the error you showed says, that `row.StickerData` is invalid because `row` is `undefined`. Did you meant to use `previewStickerData` instead?

Comment: I tried that too but it still gives the same error

Comment: instead of `(click)="openSidebar('sticker-preview-sidebar', row.StickerData)"`, use `(click)="openSidebar('sticker-preview-sidebar', previewStickerData )"`, if this does not work then even the `previewStickerData` variable is undefined and I don't know hot to help without further info

Comment: Try `{{ stickerData?.StickerData }}` in your sidebar html.

Comment: That worked thank you!@iamentafaz